# Flutter Provider showing data from wrong user

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-provider

In my application when I log in on 1 account (lets call him 'user1') and then logout of that user, then I log in on a second account ('user2'), my StreamProvider gets the correct UID from Firebase of the new user, but my StreamProviders below that use that 'uid' still show the data from the previous user.

This is an issue because in, for example, my StreamProvider<List> it gets the workouts from user1, and not from user2,... After HOT RESTARTING the app it will fix itself, but I need it to work without HOT Restarting

So I guess my question is, either, "what am I doing wrong?" or "how can I 'recreate' my StreamProviders (that use the UID) when the value of User/user.uid changes

Thanks in advance

This is the code in my main.dart, which contains all my Providers

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}



class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        StreamProvider<User>(
          create: (_) => AuthService().user,
        ),
       
      ],
      child: Builder(
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          final user = Provider.of<User>(context) ?? null;
         

          return MultiProvider(
            providers: [
              StreamProvider<List<Exercise>>(
                create: (_) => DatabaseService().exercises,
              ),
              StreamProvider<List<ExerciseCategory>>(
                create: (_) => DatabaseService().categories,
              ),
              StreamProvider<List<ExerciseEquipment>>(
                create: (_) => DatabaseService().equipment,
              ),
              StreamProvider<List<notification.Notification>>(
                create: (_) => DatabaseService().notifications,
              ),
              ChangeNotifierProvider<ExerciseFilter>(
                create: (_) => ExerciseFilter(),
              ),
              ChangeNotifierProvider<WorkoutChangeNotifier>(
                create: (_) => WorkoutChangeNotifier(),
              ),
              StreamProvider<List<UserExercise>>(
                create: (_) =>
                    DatabaseService(uid: user != null ? user.uid : '')
                        .userExercises,
              ),
              StreamProvider<List<WorkoutStreamProvider>>(
                create: (_) =>
                    DatabaseService(uid: user != null ? user.uid : '').workouts,
              ),
              StreamProvider<List<WorkoutHistory>>(
                create: (_) =>
                    DatabaseService(uid: user != null ? user.uid : '')
                        .workoutHistory,
              ),
              StreamProvider<UserSettings>(
                create: (_) =>
                    DatabaseService(uid: user != null ? user.uid : '').settings,
              ),
              StreamProvider<Nutrition>(
                create: (_) =>
                    DatabaseService(uid: user != null ? user.uid : '')
                        .nutrition,
              ),
            ],
            child: MaterialApp(
              theme: ThemeData(
                primarySwatch: Colors.grey,
                primaryTextTheme: TextTheme(
                  headline6: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16.0),
                ),
                fontFamily: "Circular",
                backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
              ),
              home: Wrapper(),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**EDIT 1: get workouts code**

```
List<WorkoutStreamProvider> _workoutStreamProviderListFromSnapshot(
    DocumentSnapshot snapshot,
  ) {
    //
    WorkoutExerciseSet _buildWorkoutExerciseSet(dynamic _set) {
      return WorkoutExerciseSet(
        reps: _set['reps'] ?? 0,
        weight: _set['weight'] ?? 0.0,
      );
    }

    List<WorkoutExerciseSet> _buildWorkoutExerciseSetList(dynamic sets) {
      List<WorkoutExerciseSet> setList = [];

      for (int i = 0; i < sets.length; i++) {
        setList.add(_buildWorkoutExerciseSet(sets[i]));
      }

      return setList;
    }

    WorkoutExercise _buildWorkoutExercise(dynamic exercise) {
      return WorkoutExercise(
        name: exercise['exerciseName'] ?? '',
        category: exercise['exerciseCategory'] ?? '',
        equipment: exercise['exerciseEquipment'] ?? '',
        restEnabled: exercise['restEnabled'] ?? true,
        restSeconds: exercise['restSeconds'] ?? 60,
        hasNotes: exercise['hasNotes'] ?? false,
        notes: exercise['notes'] ?? '',
        sets: _buildWorkoutExerciseSetList(exercise['sets']),
      );
    }

    List<WorkoutExercise> _buildWorkoutExerciseList(List<dynamic> exercises) {
      List<WorkoutExercise> workoutExerciseList = [];

      for (int i = 0; i < exercises.length; i++) {
        workoutExerciseList.add(
          _buildWorkoutExercise(exercises[i]),
        );
      }

      return workoutExerciseList;
    }

    WorkoutStreamProvider _buildWorkout(dynamic workout) {
      return WorkoutStreamProvider(
        id: workout['id'] ?? '',
        name: workout['workoutName'] ?? '',
        workoutNote: workout['workoutNote'] ?? '',
        exercises: _buildWorkoutExerciseList(workout['exercises']),
      );
    }

    List<WorkoutStreamProvider> workoutList = [];

    if (snapshot.exists && snapshot.data != null) {
      if (snapshot.data['workouts'] != null) {
        List<dynamic> workouts = snapshot.data['workouts'];

        for (int i = 0; i < workouts.length; i++) {
          workoutList.add(_buildWorkout(workouts[i]));
        }
      }
    }

    return workoutList;
  }

  Stream<List<WorkoutStreamProvider>> get workouts {
    print("GETTING WORKOUTS OF UID: " + uid);

    return userCollection
        .document(uid)
        .snapshots()
        .map(_workoutStreamProviderListFromSnapshot);
  }
```

UI

```
class WorkoutListWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<WorkoutStreamProvider> dbWorkouts =
        Provider.of<List<WorkoutStreamProvider>>(context) ?? [];

    final User user = Provider.of<User>(context) ?? null;

    final WorkoutChangeNotifier workout =
        Provider.of<WorkoutChangeNotifier>(context) ?? null;

    return ReorderableSliverList(
      delegate: ReorderableSliverChildListDelegate(
        [
          for (int i = 0; i < dbWorkouts.length; i++)
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  workout.workoutStreamProviderToChangeNotifier(dbWorkouts[i]);
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (BuildContext context) => WorkoutViewPage(),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 0.0, 8.0, 8.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: Colors.grey[400],
                      width: 1,
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
                            child: Text(
                              dbWorkouts[i].name,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 16.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Theme(
                            data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                              cardColor: Color.fromRGBO(35, 35, 35, 1),
                              dividerColor: Color.fromRGBO(70, 70, 70, 1),
                            ),
                            child: PopupMenuButton(
                              offset: Offset(0, 50),
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
                              ),
                              icon: Icon(
                                Icons.more_vert,
                              ),
                              onSelected: (selection) async {
                                if (selection == 'edit') {
                                  print('EDIT WORKOUT');
                                  workout.workoutStreamProviderToChangeNotifier(
                                      dbWorkouts[i]);

                                  Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                          WorkoutEditPage(),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                } else if (selection == 'duplicate') {
                                  print('DUPLICATE WORKOUT');

                                  dynamic result = await DatabaseService(
                                    uid: user != null ? user.uid : '',
                                  ).duplicateWorkout(dbWorkouts[i], dbWorkouts);

                                  if (result != null) {
                                    print("Workout Duplicated");
                                  }
                                } else if (selection == 'delete') {
                                  dynamic result = await DatabaseService(
                                    uid: user != null ? user.uid : '',
                                  ).removeWorkout(dbWorkouts[i], dbWorkouts);

                                  if (result != null) {
                                    print("Workout Deleted");
                                  }
                                }
                              },
                              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                  <PopupMenuItem>[
                                PopupMenuItem(
                                  height: 40.0,
                                  value: 'edit',
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Edit workout',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 17.0,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                PopupMenuItem(
                                  height: 40.0,
                                  value: 'duplicate',
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Duplicate workout',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 17.0,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                PopupMenuItem(
                                  height: 40.0,
                                  value: 'delete',
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Delete workout',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 17.0,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      for (int j = 0; j < dbWorkouts[i].exercises.length; j++)
                        Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 2.0),
                          child: Text(dbWorkouts[i].exercises[j].equipment == ""
                              ? dbWorkouts[i]
                                      .exercises[j]
                                      .sets
                                      .length
                                      .toString() +
                                  ' x ' +
                                  dbWorkouts[i].exercises[j].name
                              : dbWorkouts[i]
                                      .exercises[j]
                                      .sets
                                      .length
                                      .toString() +
                                  ' x ' +
                                  dbWorkouts[i].exercises[j].name +
                                  " (" +
                                  dbWorkouts[i].exercises[j].equipment +
                                  ")"),
                        ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
        ],
      ),
      onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
        // Move Workout
        dynamic result = DatabaseService(
          uid: user != null ? user.uid : '',
        ).reorderWorkout(oldIndex, newIndex, dbWorkouts);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: No, I get 0 errors, everything does work, and when I print out my user object (in the Builder widget under where I get the Provider.of<User>) it does show the new UID, but the Providers that have have DatabaseService(user != null ? user.uid : '') don't use the new updated UID

Comment: Why have you not added the constructor parameters in the first 4 Providers?

Comment: please share the code where you're updating the workouts.

Comment: DatabaseService() is a class which pretty much contains all my Database Functions/Streams (firebase), exercises, categories, equipment & notifications can be accessed by any user and it's read only data for them. The ones where I do give the parameter, those are use specific, so that is data that is unique for each user. Like for example: I have a list of all exercises (same for each user, so no UID required), but a user can also make it's own exercises, for those I do need the UID to fetch them, otherwise I can't get the correct 'userexercises' for that user

Comment: okay, share the requested code.

Comment: I have edited my post, you should now see my 'get workouts' code

Comment: I am asking for the code, where ui is updated with workouts.

Comment: Done, I'm sorry

Comment: Where is the loginUI? I see it's not in this widget tree!

Comment: The loginUI is completely irrelavent to the problem. The thing is, it does get the correct user uid, so the login is working, and so is the logout, it just isn't updating my providers that contain the user.uid as parameter in the constructor of the DatabaseService()

Comment: @ASADHAMEED I managed to fix it myself, thanks for the attempt to help though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix my issue by placing an if around  my Multiprovider inside the builder, and either returning my SignIn() screen if user doesn't exist and otherwise I return my multiprovider, containing the providers, and the Wrapper()

This way I force my UI to rebuild on a change in my user provider and by forcing it to rebuild it has to recall my DatabaseService() functions with the new UID

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        StreamProvider<User>(
          create: (_) => AuthService().user,
        ),
      ],
      child: Builder(
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          final user = Provider.of<User>(context) ?? null;

          return user == null
              ? MaterialApp(
                  theme: ThemeData(
                    primarySwatch: Colors.grey,
                    primaryTextTheme: TextTheme(
                      headline6: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16.0),
                    ),
                    fontFamily: "Circular",
                    backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                  ),
                  home: SignIn(),
                )
              : MultiProvider(
                  providers: [
                    StreamProvider<List<Exercise>>(
                      create: (_) => DatabaseService().exercises,
                    ),
                    StreamProvider<List<ExerciseCategory>>(
                      create: (_) => DatabaseService().categories,
                    ),
                    StreamProvider<List<ExerciseEquipment>>(
                      create: (_) => DatabaseService().equipment,
                    ),
                    StreamProvider<List<notification.Notification>>(
                      create: (_) => DatabaseService().notifications,
                    ),
                    ChangeNotifierProvider<ExerciseFilter>(
                      create: (_) => ExerciseFilter(),
                    ),
                    ChangeNotifierProvider<WorkoutChangeNotifier>(
                      create: (_) => WorkoutChangeNotifier(),
                    ),
                    StreamProvider<List<UserExercise>>(
                      create: (_) =>
                          DatabaseService(uid: user != null ? user.uid : '')
                              .userExercises,
                    ),
                    StreamProvider<List<WorkoutStreamProvider>>(
                        create: (_) =>
                            DatabaseService(uid: user != null ? user.uid : '')
                                .workouts),
                    StreamProvider<List<WorkoutHistory>>(
                      create: (_) =>
                          DatabaseService(uid: user != null ? user.uid : '')
                              .workoutHistory,
                    ),
                    StreamProvider<UserSettings>(
                      create: (_) =>
                          DatabaseService(uid: user != null ? user.uid : '')
                              .settings,
                    ),
                    StreamProvider<Nutrition>(
                      create: (_) =>
                          DatabaseService(uid: user != null ? user.uid : '')
                              .nutrition,
                    ),
                  ],
                  child: MaterialApp(
                    theme: ThemeData(
                      primarySwatch: Colors.grey,
                      primaryTextTheme: TextTheme(
                        headline6:
                            TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16.0),
                      ),
                      fontFamily: "Circular",
                      backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                    ),
                    home: Wrapper(),
                  ),
                );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, could you post your AuthService class? Thanks!